# How to use radix correct when the first argument (string) looks like this (parseInt)?

Tags: javascript, parseint, radix

As the title says, I have an array where I parse the ID (which looks like this: '58575371-58575375'). I surround it with a parseInt. What kind of radix should I use? I read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) description, but I didn't understand what I should use.

Code:

```
data[parseInt(id)] = someCoolFunction(id)
```

id = '123456-654321'

Comment: `parseInt('123456-654321')` already returns `123456`

Comment: What do you expect the return value of `parseInt(id)` to be? It may not be the right function for what you want to do. The radix simply tells the function which base to "apply" to the numeric string. E.g. `parseInt('101', 2)` is `5` vs `parseInt('101', 10)` is `101`.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to split the string across the '-' (hyphen) and then store both the parts in two different integers ?

Comment: @mdhrumil yes. The problem is that I can't commit my code because our Eslint gives me a warning that radix is missing. I've never used radix before

Comment: MDN says: "__radix__ _: An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the [string]_" So, if you know "58575371" being a decimal, then use 10 as radix.

Comment: The warning is for not using parseInt's optional second argument of radix, and while the warning may be valid, it has nothing to do with your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string through hyphen, and convert the resultant string array to a new integer array using something like this:

```
var id = '12345-67890';
var pieces = id.split('-');
var convertedArray = [];


for(i=0; i<pieces.length; i++){
    convertedArray.push(parseInt(pieces[i]));
}
```

The radix parameter in the parseInt function is optional. If you don't mention it, the default value of 10 will be applied and thus you shouldn't get error/warnings there.

Comment: "You shouldn't get error/warnings there" no but surprises maybe. `parseInt("0x66xfoo")`